# smartctl: Unable to detect device type

Tags: dual-boot, disk-management, smart

I have the following disk partition

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3964076        0   3964076   0% /dev
tmpfs             798780     9748    789032   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5 155111372 27748232 119460832  19% /
tmpfs            3993892    63824   3930068   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            3993892        0   3993892   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         91264    91264         0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop1        431360   431360         0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/159
/dev/loop2         91264    91264         0 100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/nvme0n1p1    507904    30924    476980   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs             798780       32    798748   1% /run/user/1000
```

I mount all my root as well as home. So I tried to use [smartctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/smartctl.8.html) with 
`sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1` and it showed

```
/dev/nvme0n1: Unable to detect device type
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
```

I am not sure how to determine my device type in general. I have a dual boot system (win10 + ubuntu16.04)

UPDATE:
I tried `smartctl -d ata /dev/nvme0`. I have

```
ATA device successfully opened

Use 'smartctl -a' (or '-x') to print SMART (and more) information
```

Then I tried `sudo smartctl -a -d ata /dev/nvme0`, I got

```
Read Device Identity failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```